# Wordpress api call using wp-ajax returns error 400

Tags: plugins, ajax, api

I'm quite new to doing api calls using Wordpress so bear with me.

I have this function:

```
function foo() {

$userinfo = [
    "number" => "26246426",
    "secondnumber" => "43634643"
];

$api_url = 'https://api.url.com';
$response = wp_remote_post( $api_url, array(
    // Set the Content-Type header.
    'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ),
    // Set the request payload/body.
    'body'    => json_encode( $userinfo ),
) );

$res_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

echo $res_body;

die();
}
```

This works and I get a response.

Now what I'm trying to do is send the response in an action towards my ajax that's in a script right under the php function from above (everything is happening inside a plugin file)

Here are my actions

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_foo', 'foo' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foo', 'foo' );
```

And my ajax call inside a script tag under the function

```
var ajaxscript = { ajax_url : 'mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' }


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $.ajax ({
            url: ajaxscript.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            // dataType: 'application/json',
            data: {
                // the value of data.action is the part AFTER 'wp_ajax_' in
                // the add_action ('wp_ajax_xxx', 'yyy') in the PHP above
                action: '_add_foo'
                // ANY other properties of data are passed to your_function()
                // in the PHP global $_REQUEST (or $_POST in this case)

                },
          success : function( response ){ console.log(response) },
          error : function(error){ console.log(error) }
            }) ;
});
```

I would be expecting to get back the $res_body variable but I'm getting a 400. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after a night sleep. Sometimes our brains function like that.

The problem was actually my call here, It should've been "add_foo" not "_add_foo"

```
    data: {
            // the value of data.action is the part AFTER 'wp_ajax_' in
            // the add_action ('wp_ajax_xxx', 'yyy') in the PHP above
            action: '_add_foo'
            // ANY other properties of data are passed to your_function()
            // in the PHP global $_REQUEST (or $_POST in this case)

            },
```

Answer (score -1):

Your ajax url is incorrect.

Try changing:

```
var ajaxscript = { ajax_url : 'mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' }
```

To:

```
var ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
```

And change: `url: ajaxscript.ajax_url,` to `url: ajax_url,`

But the proper way to do this is by using [wp_localize_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. I've changed what you said but still no luck. I also tried to add the script localized 

function my_action_callback() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'frontend-ajax', 'mywebsites.com/wp-content/plugins/mears-careers-login/assets/js/app.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_localize_script( 'frontend-ajax', 'frontend_ajax_object',
        array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            // 'data_var_1' => 'value 1',
            // 'data_var_2' => 'value 2',
        )
    );


}